# Can I replace a microservice inside of AKS k8s with smarter nginx config?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

### Question

Can I get nginx to call another microservice inside of AKS k8s prior to it routing to the requested api? - the goal being to speed up requests (fewer hops) and simplify build and deployment (fewer services).

### Explanation

In our currently deployed Azure AKS (Kubernetes) cluster, we have an additional service I was hoping to replace with nginx. It's a routing microservice that calls out to a identity API prior to doing the routing.

The reason is a common one I'd imagine, we recieve some kind of authentication token via some pre-defined header(s) (the standard `Authorization` header, or sometimes some bespoke ones used for debug tokens, and impersonation), we call from the routing API into the identity API with those pre-defined headers and get a user identity object in return.

We then pass on this basic user identity object into the microservices so they have quick and easy access to the user and roles.

A brief explanation would be:

- Nginx receives a request, off-loads SSL and route to the requested service.
- Routing API takes the authorization headers and makes a call to the Identity API.
- Identity API validations the authorization information and returns either an authorization error (when auth fails), or a serialized user identity object.
- Router API either returns there and then, for failure, or routes to the requested microservice (by cracking the request path), and attaches the user identity object as a header.
- Requested microservice can then turn that user identity object into a Claims Principal in the case of .NET Core for example.

[image: k8s with our own Router API]

There are obviously options for merging the Router.API and the UserIdentity.API, but keeping the separation of concerns seems like a better move. I'd just to remove the Route.API, in-order to maintain that separation, but get nginx to do that work for me.

Comment: As I saw according to your post, I may say that’s the way how nginx works. What’s your specific issue? You’ve met some unexpected error?

Comment: @Light.G No error, but reducing the number of services being hit before getting to it's destination is the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProxyKit (https://github.com/damianh/ProxyKit) could be a good alternative to nginx - it allows you to easily add custom logic to certain requests (for example I lookup API keys based on a tenant in URL) and you can cache the responses using CacheCow (see a recipe in ProxyKit source)

Comment: I _think_ after everything I've read, I'm happy with NGINX as it is (looks like the Pro version does what I need), so leaving it to do top-level routing and SSL offload is a better option. I'm liking the look of ProxyKit to replacing my Router.API with something built for the job - ours was thrown together. So get PK to call out to the identity api then route after.

Comment: Following up on this, I replaced 90% of the Router.API with ProxyKit. It was a much better solution for the internal routing. Thanks for the tip!